# Vista cmd shell thinks it's Windows Server 2008 DEBUG

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-vista, windows-command-prompt, debug

Never seen this before - My vista cmd shell started displaying everything in yellow and outputs the following as soon as I start it:

```
Setting SDK relative to C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDK/Windows/v6.1
.
Targeting Windows Server 2008 x86 DEBUG
```

**Any clue of why this could be happening and how do I go back to normal?**

I thought might've run a bat file that might've wiped my classpath ... but I checked my classpath and it seems to be fine - also I suspect the problem might be totally unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the shortcut your using to run your cmd shell.  (start, and search for simply 'cmd')

If you have the Microsoft developer tools installed, it adds a command shell entry to your start menu that initializes the environment to build software.

Comment: looks like you're right --> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /T:0E /K "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd"